# Jest rejects function fails

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

```
const fetchDataPromise = (cal) => Promise.reject("error");    

test("the fetch fails with an error2", async () => {
      await expect(fetchDataPromise()).rejects.toThrow("error");
    });
```

> ```
> Expected substring: "error"
>
> Received function did not throw
>
>   25 | 
>   26 | test("the fetch fails with an error2", async () => {
> > 27 |   await expect(fetchDataPromise()).rejects.toThrow("error");
>      |                                            ^
>   28 | });
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `await expect(fetchDataPromise()).rejects.toEqual("error");`

This will assert the rejected value is 'error'. the `toThrow` method asserts an `Error` was thrown, ie `throw new Error('fart bubble')`.